# Basic tension and equilibrium confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, statics, equilibrium

[image]

The following is what I did:

$$Fsin\theta = 60 => F = 93 N$$

$$Fcos\theta = 40 => F = 52 N$$

Why do I get different results? Does this mean the object isn't in equilibrium? How can I proceed to calculate F?

Answer (score 1):

The object is not in equilibrium. However, you can still calculate $F$. You know that the string isn't lengthening or shortening, so the net force in the direction of the string is zero.

So you can decompose the three forces in the problem into components along the string and components perpendicular to the string, and set the net force along the string to zero.